# Is there a way to validate GCP resource names without attempt to create it?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I need to validate that GCP resource name like bucket name or big query table name is valid in advance. I can not try to create it to check if creation failed due to invalid name. Is there some validation API that can check my name against specific GCP resource naming rules without creation attempt?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not such an API. The only way that I know is to validate with a regex representing the rules presented on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

### There is no way to check wheather resource name is correct before actually trying to create it.

[Naming convention in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/naming-resources#resource-name-format) however are very simple and come down basically to:

- 1-63 characters in length
- Match the regular expression a-z?
  (This means that the first character must be a lowercase letter, and all the following characters must be hyphens, lowercase letters, or digits, except the last character, which cannot be a hyphen.)